# Variable might not have been initialized, unsure how to work around

Tags: java, scope, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to assign a value to the variable "country" so that it can be returned in the midst of my out.write statements for writing to a .txt file, but I keep getting the error thrown that the variable might not have been initialized. I understand that it's due to scope in this case because of the loops I'm using, but I'm at a loss of how to work around it. Thanks in advance for any help.

PS: the variable "country" I'm referring to is brought up right at the end of this code snippet, though the interactions all occur within the bufferedwriter section.

```
    public class CarbonAnalysis{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName;
    File file;
    Scanner in;

    do{
        //try{
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid name of a file to be sorted");
            fileName = scan.next();
            file=new File(fileName);
        //}catch(IOException e){
            //System.out.println("Please enter a valid filename");
            //fileName = scan.next();
            //file=new File(fileName);
        //}
        // I originally had a try/catch clause here because initially it actually caught an exception, but now at completion it's causing an error if left in.
        // That error being: "exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement." so I've //'ed it out.
    }while(file.exists()!=true);

    in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    in.nextLine();
    int rows = in.nextInt();

    GetSortPack(rows, in);

    System.out.println("Output file CarbonDioxideAnalysis.txt has been created.");
}
private static void GetSortPack(int rows, Scanner in){
    String[] country = new String[rows];
    double[] totalCO2 = new double[rows];
    double[] roadCO2 = new double[rows];
    double[] CO2PerPerson = new double[rows];
    double[] carsPerPerson = new double[rows];

    while(in.hasNext()){
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++){
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
                if(i==1){
                    country[j] = in.next();
                }
                if(i==2){
                    totalCO2[j] = in.nextDouble();
                }
                if(i==3){
                    roadCO2[j] = in.nextDouble();
                }
                if(i==4){
                    CO2PerPerson[j] = in.nextDouble();
                }
                if(i==5){
                    carsPerPerson[j] = in.nextDouble();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        double[] sortedTotalCO2=SelectionSort(totalCO2);
        double[] sortedRoadCO2=SelectionSort(roadCO2);
        double[] sortedCO2PerPerson=SelectionSort(CO2PerPerson);
        double[] sortedCarsPerPerson=SelectionSort(carsPerPerson);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("CarbonDioxideAnalysis.txt"));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
            if(i==1){
                out.write("The country with the lowest total emissions: " + highLow(country, totalCO2, sortedTotalCO2, 2) + ".");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("The country with the highest total emissions: " + highLow(country, totalCO2, sortedTotalCO2, 1) + ".");
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Canada is ranked " + highLow(country, totalCO2, sortedTotalCO2, 3) + " out of " + rows + " countries for total lowest emissions.");
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }
            if(i==2){
                out.write("The country with the lowest total road emissions: " + highLow(country, roadCO2, sortedRoadCO2, 2));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("The country with the highest total road emissions: " + highLow(country, roadCO2, sortedRoadCO2, 1));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Canada is ranked " + highLow(country, roadCO2, sortedRoadCO2, 3) + " out of " + rows + " countries for total lowest road emissions.");
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }
            if(i==3){
                out.write("The country with the lowest per-person road emissions: " + highLow(country, CO2PerPerson, sortedCO2PerPerson, 2));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("The country with the highest per-person road emissions: " + highLow(country, CO2PerPerson, sortedCO2PerPerson, 1));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Canada is ranked " + highLow(country, CO2PerPerson, sortedCO2PerPerson, 3) + " out of " + rows + " countries for lowest per-person road emissions.");
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }
            if(i==4){
                out.write("The country with the lowest total emissions: " + highLow(country, carsPerPerson, sortedCarsPerPerson, 2));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("The country with the highest total emissions: " + highLow(country, carsPerPerson, sortedCarsPerPerson, 1));
                out.newLine();
                out.write("Canada is ranked " + highLow(country, carsPerPerson, sortedCarsPerPerson, 3) + " out of " + rows + " countries for lowest number of cars per-thousand persons.");
                out.newLine();
                out.newLine();
            }
        }
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {}
}
private static String highLow(String[] countries, double[] original, double[] sorted, int maxOrMin){
    int temp = 0;
    int canada = 0;
    int a = (sorted.length-1);
    String country = null;
        if(maxOrMin==1){
            temp=java.util.Arrays.asList(original).indexOf(sorted);
            return String.valueOf(countries[temp]);
        }else if(maxOrMin==2){
            temp=java.util.Arrays.asList(original).indexOf(sorted);
            return String.valueOf(countries[temp]);
        }else{
            canada=java.util.Arrays.asList(countries).indexOf("Canada");
            temp=java.util.Arrays.asList(original).indexOf(sorted[canada]);
            country=String.valueOf(temp);
        }
    return String.valueOf(country);
}
private static double[] SelectionSort(double[] b) {
    double[] a = new double[b.length];
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 0, b.length);
    int min=-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[min] > a[j]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i) {
            double temp = a[min];
            a[min] = a[i];
            a[i] = temp;
        }
    }
return a;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the local variables in java. So, you have to

```
public static String highLow(String[] countries, double[] original, double[] sorted, int maxOrMin){
    int temp=1;
    int Canada = 0;
    String country = null;
    ....
    ....
```

Note : I have initialized the local variables `Canada` to 0 and `country` to null.

Comment: This does cause the program to compile and run (I've done similar already), but it will now only return and write "null" for any line of code using this method. Any ideas how I would go about navigating my if loops or rewriting them so that when they changed the country variable, it would stick?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's to show you that you've made an error and are accessing arrays without making sure they have enough elements. Instead of catching the exception, write your code so it never accesses outside the array.

Second of all, in the event that AIOOBE is thrown, the country local variable wouldn't have been initialized and the compiler can't return it. A simple assignment of null or "" to it will get rid of that error.

Comment: Again, it does get rid of the error and allow it to compile and run, but the output is still incorrect. I'm not entirely sure how to make it so that method doesn't access elements outside of the array though, it looks to me as if they never would right now. I assume I'm entirely incorrect though

Comment: Did you remove the try/catch block? Do it now. If you get an exception and a stacktrace, you'll see where the problem is. Then you fix the problem in your code logic and everything will work like a charm (hint: indexOf() returns -1 if the element isn't found, and arrays don't have a -1 index). Lastly, don't **ever** put an empty catch block, unless you know what you're doing (which you don't). It's a guaranteed way to waste your time debugging. At the least, put an `e.printStackTrace()` in there.

Comment: I did remove the try/catch block and it threw an exception and a stacktrace, but it either refers to line 120 or 119 depending on the int of the index, either it being the total length of 10, or 1 under as 9. I'm sorry, I've only been trying to learn Java for the past few months, so I imagine you're entirely right in that I don't know what I'm doing yet.

Comment: Well, now you'll need to debug your code. A basic way is to print out the variables every once in a while. You can then see where you're not getting the values you're expecting.

Comment: How can I print out the variables while getting an exception thrown which ends the program? All I can do is confirm that country is still null before the exception occurs :/

Comment: By adding code between existing lines of code. Preferably between lines that are executed before the exception is thrown. Print out all the variables you're dealing with: temp, Canada, country... everything.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done. I know that it's the code within my loops causing the problem, but I simply don't have the knowledge to deal with it, nor do I know where I could find it. That's why I've posted this question. Can you please just straightforward help me arrive at some conclusion? I've been trying to just do it on my own but I can't figure this out.

Comment: If you're getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, then it means you're accessing an array with either index < 0 or index >= arr.length. Find places where you're accessing arrays, check which indexes you're accessing, backtrack and find where your logic goes wrong. Heck, even take a piece of paper and track how your logic works.

Comment: I added the entirety of my code, is there anything you can see that I'm messing up?

Comment: Sorry, I won't be doing your debugging for you. I don't need to learn how to do it anymore, you do. I already told you to pepper your code with System.out.println() statements to see where you're getting wrong values.